# Linq2EF: Return DateTime with a TimeZone Offset

Tags: datetime, linq-to-sql, timezone

Our database has all times stored as UTC, and we know the user's current timezone, so want to return it relative to that. So we want to incorporate the offset in a LINQ projection as so:

```
var users = from u in this.Context.Users
            select new UserWithCorrectedDate
            {
                Id = u.Id,
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                LastName = u.LastName,
                RegistrationDate = u.RegistrationDate.Value.AddHours(-5)
            };
```

Of course, Linq2EF cannot convert "`AddHours`" into a canonical function. Is there another way to do this?

UPDATE:

Another thought, if the timezone offset was stored in the database as another column, would there be a way to have the DB perform the calculation (date + offset)?

Comment: What is the result set size of the query?  Just do it in memory

Comment: It is 5000 users, but only 10 are displayed, so I didn't want to use a ToList(). Actually, filters are applied to the query after this step, further reason not to convert to objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq to Entities supports SqlFunctions. If you know the offset number of hours you could do something like this:

```
var users = from u in this.Context.Users
            select new UserWithCorrectedDate
            {
               Id = u.Id,
               FirstName = u.FirstName,
               LastName = u.LastName,
               RegistrationDate = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hour", -5, u.RegistrationDate.Value)
            };
```

If you want to be more precise by using the Timezone function, you could do something like this (this is a bit of a workaround):

```
public static DateTime UtcToNewYorkTime(DateTime utcDateTime)
{
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

        DateTime converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, tzi);
        return converted;
}
```

And then in your POCO UserWithCorrectedDate object, have a get only property for the Timezoned date ie.

```
public class UserWithCorrectDate
{
    public DateTime UTCDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime NYDate
    {
         get
        {
            return Utilities.UtcToNewYorkTime(this.UTCDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I tried to use your second approach it says : The specified type member 'NYDate' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: because its not supported by linq, you will need todo .ToList() before, but then you lose the lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to do this is to convert to a list, and just linq to object to get it done:

```
from u in this.Context.Users.ToList()
select new { ... }
```